# I have a challenge where I am stuck

Tags: javascript

```
var launchRocket = function (sequence) {
  if (sequence === 321) {
    var _$_f307 = ["className", "animation-window",
      "getElementsByClassName", "body", "animation-window animate",
      "z0", "omf", "orward", "innerHTML", "rocket-code"];
    document[_$_f307[3]][_$_f307[2]](_$_f307[1])[0][_$_f307[0]] = _$_f307[4];
    var e = _$_f307[5];
    var x = _$_f307[6];
    var n = _$_f307[7];
    document[_$_f307[3]][_$_f307[2]](_$_f307[9])[0][_$_f307[8]] = e + x + n;
  }
}
```

Now, I understand that I may not be phrasing this question as best as possible, however, I understand that the 'document' part is now equal to the variable string 'z0omforward'.

My question is, how do I run this in a console to run var launchRocket.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: first run that snippet in console. and then call launchRocket by passing a number.If you want to know more about functions check this https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`launchRocket` is a function, so you call it with `launchRocket(sequence)`, where `sequence`is the sequence you'd like to pass to the function. This can be a variable as in

```
var sequence = 123;
launchRocket(sequence);
```

or simply

```
launchRocket(123);
```